# Entire function is constant in a disc is constant in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire function such that $f(z)=c\:, \: \forall z\in  D(z_0,r) $ show that $f$ is constant in the entire plane.

---

$(i)$ since $f $ is entire,   I can write $f=\sum_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n=c+0+0+...=c,\: z\in \mathbb{C}$  thus $f$ is constant

$(ii)$ Consider $g=f-c$, then $g$ is entire with  an uncountable number of zeros in $D(z_0,r)$, and so in  $\overline{D(z_0,r)}$ , if $Z_n$ are the zeros of $g$ in the compact  $\overline{D(z_0,r)}$  then $Z_{n_k}$ has a limit and since $g(z_n)=0$ by the identity theorem $g\equiv 0$  in  $D(z_0,r)$ and by $(i)$ $g$ is constant thus $f$ also

Can I show $(ii)$ without the use of $(i)$ ?  Because then there is no point for doing $(ii)$

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why, thank you.

Comment: I ddint downvote; your formula in (i) is wrong; you cannot write $Z_n$ for **the** zeros because the set of zeros is not countable. You can pick out an arbitrary sequence of zeros.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think $(i)$ is ok now

Comment: no, check with an example. exp(x) is entire, and equals $\sum x^n/n!$. $1/(1-x)$ is not entire and equals $\sum x^n$; the derivatives (also: not powers) are not all 1.

Comment: @CalvinKhor you mean not all $0$ ?

Comment: @CalvinKhor how come $g^n(z_0)\neq 0$ for some $n$ ?

Comment: @CalvinKhor can you explain why $i$ is still wrong, I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (i) is correct and already shows that $f = c$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $g(z) = f(z) - c, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. Take a sequence, let's say $z_{n} \in D(z_{0} , \frac{r} {2} )$ which converges to $z_{0}$. Because $f(z)= c , \forall z \in D(z_{0} , r) \Rightarrow f(z_{n} ) = c, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow g(z_{n}) = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. $ The fact that g is entire and has a point which is a limit point and also a root for $g$ makes $g$ the zero function.